# Render alert from controller after ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, alert

I am making an ajax call to post my data

```
                $.ajax({
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Interview/SaveInterview',
                data: totalInterview,
                success: function (response) {
                    //$('#divNotification').html(response);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert('failed');
                }
            });
```

It calls the controller method

```
        public ActionResult SaveInterview(List<InterviewViewModel> totalInterview)
    {
        //saves successfully.......

        if (blnSaveResult)
        {
            Success(string.Format("<b>{0}</b> was successfully added to the database.", "Interview"), true);
        }
        else
        {
            Danger("Oops! Something went wrong! Please check your form and try again.");
        }

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            //return View("AddInterview");
            return PartialView("_Notifications");
        }
        else
        {
            return View("AddInterview");
        }
        //return this.Json(new { success = blnSaveResult }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The Success Method:

```
        public void Success(string message, bool dismissable = false)
    {
        AddAlert(AlertStyles.Success, message, dismissable);
    }

        private void AddAlert(string alertStyle, string message, bool dismissable)
    {
        var alerts = TempData.ContainsKey(Alerts.TempDataKey)
            ? (List<Alerts>)TempData[Alerts.TempDataKey]
            : new List<Alerts>();

        alerts.Add(new Alerts
        {
            AlertStyle = alertStyle,
            Message = message,
            Dismissable = dismissable
        });

        TempData[Alerts.TempDataKey] = alerts;
    }
```

This is nothing but a method that passes data to a partial view (_Notifications) to show an alert.

_Notifications.cshtml

```
@{
     var alerts = TempData.ContainsKey(Alerts.TempDataKey) ? (List<Alerts>)TempData[Alerts.TempDataKey] : new List<Alerts>();
if (alerts.Any())
{
    <hr />
}

foreach (var alert in alerts)
{
    var dismissableClass = alert.Dismissable ? "alert-dismissable" : null;
    <div class="alert alert-@alert.AlertStyle @dismissableClass">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            @if (alert.Dismissable)
            {
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="material-icons">clear</i></span>
                </button>
            }
            @Html.Raw(alert.Message)
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

}

What should happen is the alert should get called and show on my main view. It just doesn't show. I don't know why. 
I have tried rendering the partial view, doesn't work.

My main view renders my partial (alert) view like this:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_Notifications");}
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: When you debug it, after what step is the `TempData[Alerts.TempDataKey]` empty? You can also place a breakpoint inside `_Notifications.cshtml`. Also, are you certain your `Success()` method is calling `AddAlert()`? It would be helpful if you post the code of `Success()` too, since nothing seems to be wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: Also, you have commented out this `//$('#divNotification').html(response);` in your ajax request. Maybe your controller is returning the alert just fine, but you are doing nothing on success of the ajax request.

Comment: I don't understand... If the alert (_Notifications) were being returned fine, (which is actually true, the controller goes to _notifications), what do I do in the ajax success, why can't it render the alert in my main view??!! BTW, I have updated the code to add Success method code.

Comment: Did you try commenting the code I suggested in JS and does it work? Since it is an ajax request, it is done in the background and you have to explicitly express what you need to do in your Javascript code if the request is successful e.g. you can alert it in the browser or you can write the response in an HTML element. [You can read more about it here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) and [here since you are using jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: " Did you try commenting the code I suggested in JS and does it work? "  - Which code are you suggesting I comment? Everything seems to be working, the controller goes to _Notifications and the alert rendering code is executed. I have placed an alert (a normal jquery alert) in the ajax success which also gets called; however the alert(_Notifications) doesn't show in my Main view. It doesn't even render. I searched it using dev tools.

Comment: I meant did you try removing the comment `//$('#divNotification').html(response);` i.e. changing it to `$('#divNotification').html(response);`. That might not work as well (depending on your HTML) but it is certain that you need to do something with the response you get from the endpoint.

Comment: Removing the comment doesn't doesn't help, the response is an object {success=true}. It doesn't change anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142359/discussion-between-granit-and-stylojack-10).